# Load images outside apache directory

Tags: apache, tomcat, web

Well, I have a website in apache directory: `/var/www/html`. Previously I had all my web images in `/var/www/html/media`, so I used to put `/media/imgX.jpg`for loading them.  but now I need to put them in `/mnt/imgs`. 
For some reason, using this path does not work the same way as before.

I think it has something to do with permissions using files from outside apache directory but I am not sure about it. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to add directories to Apache httpd is to use the "alias" module:

```
Alias /images "/mnt/imgs"
<Directory "/mnt/imgs>
    Options Indexes
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Once you have set up this, test it with: "yourdomain.com/images".

Of course:

- The directory "/mnt/imgs" need the appropriate rights, so Apache Httpd can access it. Therefore you need to find out the group it runs with.
- These files will be available to the public, if you dont secure them.
- Once this is functional, remove the "indexes" line from the snippet above.